# DHTMLX Grid Row Selection

Tags: angular, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlx grid with angular 2. I want to select/unselect row using checkboxes instead of row click in dhtmlx grid. How can we do that or how to unselect a single row in grid. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of DHTMLX do you use ?

Comment: It is dhtmlxSuite_v502_pro. But i am not able to find any function to unselect a single row in grid and when i try to hide row selection and trying to do it with checkboxes then row selection is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To unselect all rows use this method:     `myGrid.clearSelection();`

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxgrid_clearselection.html

There is no way to grammatically deselect a single row.

https://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=50697&p=140955&hilit=unselect+row#p140955